# Getting the resource creator for a Resource in Azure by PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to get the reource creator for a resource through Powershell for implementing a tagging policy. I have tried using `Get-AzLog`, however, I was not able to deduce the creator of the resource.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post what you tried>

Comment: Get-AzLog -ResourceId <resource-id-of-the-resource>.

Answer (score 1):

**[`Get-AzLog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit)** is the way, By default it returns only the information for the last 7 days, if you know the time and date, you can try the following,

```
Get-AzLog -ResourceGroup ExampleGroup -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)
```

Comment: Also try this one https://github.com/jrudlin/Azure/blob/226bf13e5e607150c22e891aae4a11b163953faf/General/Get-RecentAzResource.ps1

Answer (score 0):

there is no api call that exposes the creator of the resources. You can try and assume that you can get the latest `write` entry from the Activity Log for the resource and assume that is when the resource was created, hence the initiator would be the owner, but that is just wrong. there is no guarantee that is in fact true

Comment: Is there a way this can be done through Powershell?

Comment: no, read the answer, there is no api that exposes this property. it cannot be done at all, at least reliably.

Comment: Well, i meant getting the latest write entry from the activity log.

Comment: with filters, powershell got filters